# Create ID when exploding dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to explode a dataframe series which retains the list position in order to create an another index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255]], 'B': [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255]]})

print(df)

        A                 B
    0  [255, 255, 255]  [255, 255, 255]
    1  [0, 0, 0]        [0, 0, 0]
    2  [255, 255, 255]  [255, 255, 255]
```

Then explode:

df.apply(pd.Series.explode)

```
       A   B
    0  255 255
    0  255 255
    0  255 255
    1  0 0
    1  0 0
    1  0 0
    2  255 255
    2  255 255
    2  255 255
```

What I would like to do is create a third column based on the position of the value in the list, so:

```
       A   B   C
    0  255 255 item1
    0  255 255 item2
    0  255 255 item3
    1  0 0     item1
    1  0 0     item2
    1  0 0     item3
    2  255 255 item1
    2  255 255 item2
    2  255 255 item3
```

In reality there may be n terms in the list, but i've only used 3 to keep things concise. I thought about converting the list into a dictionary and then turning the index into a column, but not sure if this is the best approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `explode` then `cumcount`

```
s = pd.concat([df[[x]].explode(x) for x in ['A','B']],axis=1)
s['C'] = s.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).radd('item')
s
Out[476]: 
     A    B      C
0  255  255  item1
0  255  255  item2
0  255  255  item3
1    0    0  item1
1    0    0  item2
1    0    0  item3
2  255  255  item1
2  255  255  item2
2  255  255  item3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `range` function

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255]], 'B': [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255]]})
>>> df
                 A                B
0  [255, 255, 255]  [255, 255, 255]
1        [0, 0, 0]        [0, 0, 0]
2  [255, 255, 255]  [255, 255, 255]
>>> # add list order as C column
>>> df['C'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: [f'item{i+1}' for i in range(len(x))])
>>> df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
     A    B      C
0  255  255  item1
0  255  255  item2
0  255  255  item3
1    0    0  item1
1    0    0  item2
1    0    0  item3
2  255  255  item1
2  255  255  item2
2  255  255  item3
```